# Dynamically select a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `SELECT` statement and I would like to use the result of one of the columns in another `SELECT` statement.

Example:

```
SELECT t.day, t.hour, 
    CASE t.event_name IS NULL
    THEN (SELECT t.day --I would like to select on a day(ie the value of t.day)
          FROM   other_events)
    ELSE t.event_name
    END as Event_Name
FROM   event_t t
```

`other_event` is a table and the columns are days; so if I don't have `event` in `event_t`, I will have it in `other_event` under that specific day.

Of course this will not work and I was wondering if it's even possible in T-SQL.

Comment: will the row exist in either event_t OR other_events, but never in both? If that;s the case, coud you use a UNION?

Comment: yes it will. I thought of using unions or multiple case statements (if Monday then, if Tuesday then,....) but I was wondering if there is something shorter.

Comment: Then make a `select...,  coalesce(t.event_name, (case when... when...else end)`

Comment: So no shorter way? I can't use the value of t.day as the column I wan to select in the second select statement?

Comment: Well, CTE could help, but why not make a view based on the other_event table, then (the same, it's just "permanent"). Cause the CTE (or the VIEW) will have the same logic (7 UNION or CASE WHEN) inside the query or in the CTE, which doens't change a lot. If it's in a view, it's "deported", and query looks simple. Depends on need.

Comment: If the event name is `NULL`, which event do you want to select from the other table? What are the conditions? It seems it's a simple matter of using a `JOIN` and `COALESCE`.

Comment: I think I answer it in the question. Just in case: if event_name from event_t table is NULL go to other_events table and extract the event in that day.

Answer (score 2):

If all the days you want are in the first table this should work:

```
SELECT t1.day,
       t1.hour,
       COALESCE(t1.event, t2.event) AS event
FROM   event_t t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN other_events t2
                    ON t1.day = t2.day
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but I'm not sure that's the condition for the `JOIN` (OP is not clear). Also, `COALESCE(t1.event, t2.event) AS event` could replace  `CASE...`

Comment: Noted and updated. Yes it is hard to tell for sure if all days are included in first table or what would need to be joined on